# How transform grouping variable to columns in R?

Tags: r

I used the follwoing dataset

```
data.frame(Group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
           time= c("10:30","10:45","10:15","10:30","10:20","10:15"),
           value= c(1,2,3,1,5,6))
```

and want to get the following table

[image]

I tried dcast() function from reshape2 package, but did not figure out how split Group variable based on time and value variables. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>%
  mutate(Val=paste0('Group',Group)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Val,values_from=Group)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  time  value GroupA GroupB
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1 10:30     1 A      B     
2 10:45     2 A      NA    
3 10:15     3 A      NA    
4 10:20     5 NA     B     
5 10:15     6 NA     B
```

**Update:** Using new data:

```
#Code 2
df %>%
  mutate(id=row_number(),
         Val=paste0('Group',Group)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Val,values_from=Group) %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  time  value GroupA GroupB
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1 10:30     1 A      NA    
2 10:30     1 A      NA    
3 10:45     2 A      NA    
4 10:15     3 A      NA    
5 10:30     1 NA     B     
6 10:20     5 NA     B     
7 10:15     6 NA     B
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. However, if in example duplicate first values of each columns, I will get ```list()``` inside the cell. How can I avoid it (using kind of ```unique()``` function). new dataset is ```data.frame(Group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"),
           time= c("10:30","10:30","10:45","10:15","10:30","10:20","10:15"),
           value= c(1,1,2,3,1,5,6))```

Comment: @ErkoTru I have updated with the new data, please let me know if that works!

Answer (score 3):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, time + value ~ paste0("group", Group), value.var = "Group")

#    time value groupA groupB
# 1 10:15     3      A   <NA>
# 2 10:15     6   <NA>      B
# 3 10:20     5   <NA>      B
# 4 10:30     1      A      B
# 5 10:45     2      A   <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  transform(
    df,
    grpName = paste0("Group", Group)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = c("time", "value"),
  timevar = "grpName"
)
```

which gives

```
   time value Group.GroupA Group.GroupB
1 10:30     1            A            B
2 10:45     2            A         <NA>
3 10:15     3            A         <NA>
5 10:20     5         <NA>            B
6 10:15     6         <NA>            B
```